# Calling between two parties and connect them to talk

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

Basically i am trying to achieve calling between two parties on their mobile numbers. I am using PHP laravel.

1. Every agent has a respective form which collects the phone number of a visitor.
2. When the agent form is filled out via visitors.
3. I want Twilio API to call to the agent first.
4. If the agent receives the call then it should call on visitor's phone number.

and connect these two parties.

Thats all

```
$client = new Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
        try {
            $call = $client->account->calls->create($agent_number, $twilio_number,
                array("url" => $url)
            );    
            echo "Started call: " . $call->sid;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
```

its calling the agent's phone numbers.. but here is what i want
when the agent receive the call then it should call on visitor's phone numbers.

I have updated my code here..

```
Route::get('call', function() {

    $AccountSid = 'SID HERE';
    $AuthToken = 'AUTH TOKEN HERE';

    $twilio_number = "TWILIO NUMBER HERE";
    $agent_number = "AGENT NUMBER HERE";
    $visitor_phone = urlencode(str_replace(' ','','VISITOR NUMBER HERE'));

    $host = parse_url(Request::url(), PHP_URL_HOST);


    $client = new Client($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
    try {
        $call = $client->account->calls->create($agent_number, $twilio_number,
            array(
                "url" => "http://$host/outbound/$visitor_phone"
            )
        ); 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

});



Route::get('/outbound/{visitor_phone}', function($visitor_phone) {
    $sayMessage = 'Thanks for contacting our sales department. Our
    next available representative will take your call.';

    $twiml = new Twiml();
    $twiml->say($sayMessage, array('voice' => 'alice'));
    $twiml->dial($visitor_phone);

    $response = Response::make($twiml, 200);
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    return $response;
});
```

and in my TWILIO webhook i have

```
website.com/outbound/visitor_number  HTTP GET REQUEST
```

i can get to my outbound message
Thanks for contacting our sales department. Our next available representative will take your call. but it doesn't dail the visitor number after that. it just disconnects the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Your updated code seems quite close to what I think you'd need. As you have, you make the outbound call to your agent and then setup a webhook URL to use TwiML to dial onwards to the visitor's number.

I don't know Laravel well, but looking up how to deal with parameters in the routes I think your issue lies there.

You have:

```
Route::get('/outbound', function($visitor_phone) {
```

But the [routing docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters) say you need to define where your URL parameter will appear in the path. So, to me, it looks like you need the route to be:

```
Route::get('/outbound/{visitor_phone}', function($visitor_phone) {
```

Check that out and see if it helps. If not, I imagine that you will be getting an error in your Laravel application as well as on the phone, so it would be useful to see that error too.

Comment: Hi,
Yes, i also noticed the routing issue and have fixed it. however after fixing the routing issue.. it doesn't read or go to webhook get request to TwiML url.

It simply calls on my number .. and it doesn't read TwiML message  and it disconnects.

Debugger error
Error - 12100

however parsing is fine i have validated too.
but what i have noticed just below the error

there is Request Inspector which shows request url
it shows GET request and http://website.com

maybe its not going to http://website.com/outbound/visitor_phone

Comment: Request inspector shows get is going to www.website.com 
maybe 'url' isn't going through webhook?

Comment: ok so i tried with post url then i got this: Error - 11200 HTTP status code 419..
and tried with get url then i am getting Error - 12100 parsing error.

Comment: ok it appears , it doesn't work with get but post was being blocked by laravel routing for CSRF protection. it worked .. thanks for helping. i will mark your answer as correct since you pointed out my routing issue.

Comment: Glad you got there in the end! You should replace your CSRF protection with [Twilio request validation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security#validating-requests) to ensure that others can't read your webhook responses.

Comment: Is there any that twilio allows to add two incoming webhooks? i have two domain separate domains, in one domain twilio is working fine but i want to use the same account in my separate domain and add another webhook for my outbound calls. is it possible?

Comment: You can't do two incoming webhooks, instead you could receive the webhook with one application then spread it out to the two yourself. Note that if you want to respond with TwiML, then only the first webhook can do so. For outbound calls you can set the webhook URL each time as part of the API request, but still only one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This is from the official site of the **Twillio**. I think you can do this by performing [Autopilot Call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api#conference-calls-queueing).

> Autopilot uses natural language understanding (NLU) to detect what
>   users are saying and matches it to Tasks. Tasks can be programmed to
>   collect data, answer questions or **connect calls to other users**. They
>   are trained to recognize different phrases or ways users might express
>   the a given Task.

Or by using Warm-transfer functionality of [twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/warm-transfer).

> Warm transfer eliminates this problem. Using Twilio-powered warm
>   transfers, **your agents will have the ability add other people to an
>   in-progress phone call to provide a seamless customer experience**.

Comment: Basically i simply want whenever USER A receives the call on their mobile.
then the system should call USER B's phone number and connect them.

Comment: Yeah you can do it in both these article its mentioned you can call other person while on a call with first person. Go through the document and linked i have share. Warm-transfer is what you are looking for.

Comment: thank you, i have updated my code but still having some problem .. it says an error occurred.. not sure whats going on..

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the click to call example on the Twilio Website, there is also a PHP/Laravel example:

[Build Click-to-Call into your Web Application](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/click-to-call)

You can modify the example above to return the Twilio Number noun URL (and Gather verb) to offer whisper capability for the agent, so they have the option to accept the call or not.

[TwiML™ Voice:](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-url)

Comment: Basically i simply want whenever USER A receives the call on their mobile. then the system should call USER B's phone number and connect them